# How to define ModelForm for multiple fields with the same name?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to define a `ModelForm to validate a form which have several`choice` fields , like this:

```
<form role="form" action="/create/poll" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="title">  
    <input type="text" name="choice" ><br>
    <input type="text" name="choice" ><br> 
    <input type="text" name="choice" ><br>

 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Since `Poll` and `Choice` are differnt models, I have define two ModelForms as:

```
class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model= Poll 
            fields= ('title',)  

class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model= Choice 
            fields= ('choice',)
```

The view:

```
def create_poll(request):
    form = PollForm()

    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
        pform = PollForm(request.POST)
        cform = ChoiceForm(request.POST)
        if pform.is_valid():
            poll = pform.save(commit = False)
            poll.title = pform.cleaned_data['title']
            poll.creator = request.user            
            poll.pub_date = timezone.now()
            poll.save()

            if cform.is_valid(): #This condition not met
                for c in cform: 
                    if c != "":
                        choice = cform.save(commit = False)
                        choice.poll = poll.id
                        choice.choice = cform.cleaned_data['c']
                        choice.save()
```

The problem is that the choices are not saved because `ChoiceForm` is not validated.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `ChoiceForm` only has one field called `choice`, how would it be able to validate an HTML form containing many choice inputs? I think you would be better off using an InlineFormSet to produce your form in the first place. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: @ChidG Can you please elaborate your answer by providing the relevant ModelForm? I could not figure it out by reading the doc.

Comment: Your model form is fine (assuming you want to use it to edit a model with one field called choice). Your problem is that you are trying to map that to a manually written html form with many fields called choice. This is operator error, not a technical problem. The solutions are: 1. Use Django's inbuilt form template tags rather than writing your own HTML and 2. Use a formset. Isn't the Django tutorial a polls app? Maybe you should go back and do that, because there are some basic Django things that you should understand before you attempt something like this.